# Resolving dynamic types in .NET 4 vs SL 5

Tags: .net, generics, dynamic

I have the following code working in Silverlight 5:

```
public void Send(Notification notification)
{
    // Because the variable is passed as Notification, we have to trick the
    // type-inference feature of the runtime so the message will be sent using
    // the actual type of the object.
    // Using the dynamic keyword, we can convert the type of the object passed
    // to the Send method.
    // This allows subscribers to register for messages using the generic interface.
    dynamic stronglyTypedNotification = Convert.ChangeType(notification,
                                                           notification.GetType(),
                                                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    SendCore(stronglyTypedNotification);
}

private void SendCore<T>(T notification)
    where T : Notification
{
    foreach (var handlerFactory in Handlers)
    {
        var handler = handlerFactory.Value as INotificationHandler<T>;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler.Handle(notification);
        }
    }
}
```

I have to port this code over to run in a WPF application.

When I run it in my WPF application and set a breakpoint inside the SendCore method, T is not the correct type.  I can only assume this is because generics are supposed to be staticly defined so the compiler has created the version of SendCore it thinks it will need at runtime.  I guess Silverlight handles this differently because this code works perfectly in SL.

The goal of this code is to locate any of the objects contained in the Handlers collection that implement INotificationHandler where T is the type of the object passed to the Send method (subclassing the base Notification class) then call the Handle(T n) method on those objects.

How can I do this in my WPF app?

**UPDATE**

After some additional testing, I am finding more peculiar results.  When I set a breakpoint on the first line of the SendCore method and inspect T and notification, I find:

- Intellisense indicates that T is "GenericNotification" which is
  legitimate class in the assembly.
- Intellisense indicates that "notification" is the correct,
  strongly-typed class (DataChangedNotification).
- DataChangedNotification does NOT subclass GenericNotification in any
  way.  Both subclass Notification.
- Because T is resolving to GenericNotification, attempting to cast
  each handler to INotificationHandler<T> will fail because none
  implement INotificationHandler<GenericNotification>

**Given that this exact code works in Silverlight, a Console application and another WPF application (as well as David's test in LINQpad), what in the world could be going on?**

The only thing I can think of mentioning is that the code actually exists in a Class Library that is referenced by the WPF application.  Not sure that matters because I tested that scenario in another (new) WPF application and had the correct results.

Comment: When you say "it's the wrong type" what type is it?

Comment: BTW: It's Daniel, not David. From your update, I assume you are simply passing the wrong variable or looking at the wrong code! There is no possible way a `DataChangedNotification` would be passed as a `GenericNotification` when they are siblings in the class hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me and that's expected. I would have been surprised if it was different.

```
void Main()
{
    Send(new NA());
    Send(new NB());
}

public class Notification {}
public class NA : Notification {}
public class NB : Notification {}

public void Send(Notification notification)
{
    dynamic stronglyTypedNotification
        = Convert.ChangeType(notification,
                             notification.GetType(),
                             CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    SendCore(stronglyTypedNotification);
}

public void SendCore<T>(T notification) where T : Notification
{
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(T));
}
```

This outputs

```
typeof (NA) 
typeof (NB)
```

Comment: I don't get this result. (You might want to update your post with the actual output as what is shown is not what your code produces.)  Regardless with type I pass into the Send method, typeof(T) always returns GenericNotification.

Comment: A couple of things to make it more comparitive: 1) make Notification abstract.  2) Put all of the notificiation code (everything but Main) into a class library referenced from the WPF Application.  3) While I believe checking typeof(T) will indicate if the rest of the code will work, keep in mind that I am trying to use the type to cast an object to INotificationHandler<T>. For a truly accurate test, that part should be replicated as well.  Not sure any of this makes a difference, but it would make your test more complete.

Comment: @SonOfPirate: May **you** should start with my code and change things until it doesn't work anymore the way you expect it. Based on this information you should ask a new question.

Comment: Based on that screen shot, you are not testing the code in a WPF Application.  Running it in LINQPad is not the same thing. In an actual .NET app, Console.WriteLine(typeof(T)) will result in the type information being written out.  There is some 'hidden' logic going on inside LINQPad.  Put this code in a console app and you'll see something like ConsoleApplication1.NA and ConsoleApplication1.NB.

Comment: @SonOfPirate: Stop arguing, start testing. LINQPad or WPF, it doesn't matter one bit. The type inference happening is the same and your console application clearly shows that. You, too, are getting `NA` and `NB` instead of `Notification`. I am very certain that your problem is something else entirely - because of that you need to check **your** code. Type inference is working as expected.

Comment: I disagree that it doesn't matter. LINQpad is interpreting your code, not running it as would be the case in an actual application. This is proven by the custom output, not to mention that the code would not compile as-is in an application.  But, from your tone, I can see you feel you know better.  Unfortunately, none of this has brought me any closer to an answer why the same code will work when used in other projects but not in the project where I need it to work.  If you can answer that question, I'm all ears, otherwise I'll be getting back to searching for a solution.

Comment: @SonOfPirate: This is total nonsense. LINQPad is compiling the code into a temporary assembly which is than loaded and executed. There is no "interpretation" happening at all. The only thing that it does is redirecting the output of Console.WriteLine so it can display it in its results window. None of this has brought you any closer to a solution because you are not willing to hear and accept what I am telling you: The type inference *is working as expected*. **Your** console application proves that, too.

Comment: You really should start from my code and change it to your code in little steps until it doesn't work anymore OR you could start from your code and change it to my code until it starts working. The discussion we are having is showing that you are *totaly* off track here. I can't possibly answer why it is not working in your application as the problem is within your code, in parts you haven't shown.

Answer (score 1):

Despite the obvious personality clash, I am giving credit to Daniel for pushing me to continue digging deeper and deeper into the problem.  I am at the same time requesting that it be removed as I see it providing no value for anyone else.

As it turns out, the problem did originate elsewhere and was being masked by a simple ToString() overload.

The first problem: The behavior I was seeing (and reporting) is the result of another developer helpfully adding a ToString override to the base Notification class that displays the name of the object in the debugger instead of the data type.  This is why looking at the 'notification' parameter in VS displayed the expected type name.  In reality, the type of object being passed in was GenericNotification.

Once I realized this was happening, I was able to open our framework code (separate solution built independently) to see where the object was instantiated.  There I found that the .NET version of the file was implemented differently than the Silverlight version.  We use MEF for dependency injection and the Silverlight version of the code was resolving the data type against an imported list of supported types.  The .NET version used a switch statement (ugh!).

So, I changed the .NET version to dynamically create the object using MEF to help resolve the type and viola!  Everything is now working as expected and the pressure has been eased (this is a critical function of our software, so having it not work...).

Comment: Nice job finding that one out! Sorry for getting so annoyed, but I just ***knew*** that it was something else and you would never find out if you continued arguing with me :-) If you want your question removed flag it for moderator attention.